# How modelbuilder works

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

i have a question about relations between entities created in Code-First:

I have Models:

```
public class ProjectGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectGroupID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectGroupName { get; set; }

    //FK
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<List> Lists { get; set; }
}


public class File
{
    [Key]
    public int FileID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectGroupID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Ścieżka pliku")]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Data Zapisu")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FileSaveDate { get; set; }//no NULL=>error
    [Display(Name="Suma MD5")]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public string FileMD5Hash { get; set; }
    public string IPHost { get; set; }
    public int FileTemplateID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProjectGroupID")]
    public virtual ProjectGroup ProjectGroup { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FileTemplateID")]
    public virtual FileTemplate FileTemplate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<List> Lists { get; set; }//klucz obcy dla listy

}

public class List
{
    [Key]
    public int ListID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectGroupID { get; set; }
    public int FileID { get; set; }
    public bool Modified { get; set; }
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
    public bool Alive { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }  //referencja,przekazanie nazwy FK
    [ForeignKey("ProjectGroupID")]
    public virtual ProjectGroup ProjectGroup { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FileID")]
    public virtual File File { get; set; }
}
```

And Context:

```
public class AWZDContext : DbContext
{
    public AWZDContext()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
    public DbSet<List> Lists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RemotePC> RemotePCs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectGroup> ProjectGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FileTemplate> FileTemplates { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<File>()                
            .HasRequired(f=>f.ProjectGroup)
            .WithMany(t=>t.Files)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<List>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.ProjectGroup)
            .WithMany(d=>d.Lists)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

}
```

when I created models, I got the following errors: problem with multi-cascade delete. I added modelbuilder in on model creating.
First I added no parameter in `WithMany()` and it doubled relations in database [like this](http://s23.postimg.org/rn0la4wl7/Przechwytywanie.png)

This created many double relations between List and ProjectGroup (File, the same, read below).
when changed to WithMany(d=>d.Lists) relations looks ok, made only once like between File and ProjectGroup.

Does modelBuilder double the effect of [foreignKey] in model?
Can anyone explain how this works? Why did it double relation earlier, with no parameter in WithMany()